# Swipeable option for Materialize Tabs - Javascript Initialization

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, materialize

I'm trying to make the Materialize tabs swipeable in a Rails 5 app, the tabs work perfectly but they're just not swipeable!

I've tried the following so far to no avail:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul.tabs').tabs({
    swipeable: true
  });
});
```

On turbolinks load:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){
  $('ul.tabs').tabs({
    swipeable: true
  });
});
```

And the tabs still aren't swipeable, are the options properly being declared here?

If you need the documentation for some quick reference: http://materializecss.com/tabs.html

Answer (score 0):

Try following,

```js
$(document).on('ready turbolinks:load', function() {
  $('ul.tabs').tabs({
    swipeable: true
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks, It fixed other problem I had :) , my tabs were not reloading and now they do. However the code I have inside is : ``swipable: false``